# Determine polarity of feedback circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, circuit-design, feedback

This is an example from Feedback chapter in Fundamentals of Microelectronics by Razavi.

As you can see from the picture, the author gives two questions (why?). Could you check if my answers are correct.

*If Iin goes up, VX tends to rise (why?), thus raising ID1. As a result, Vout falls and ID2 decreases, allowing VX to rise (why?)*

1. First question: if Iin goes up, VX tends to rise(why?):

Because there is a capacitance between node X and ground, when Iin increases the voltage at node X will be equal to Iin multiplied by input impedance and therefore Vx will increase.

2. First question: Vout falls and ID2 decreases, allowing VX to rise (why?):

Vout decreases, the current through M2 decreases so the current through input capacitance increases and thus Vx increases.

[image]

Comment: Forget the input capacitance, revisit your answer to (1) in the light of your current answer to (2).

Comment: Hi, is my answer for question 1 correct? If so, I don't see why the answer for question 2 is wrong.

Comment: No. Your answer for 1 is more wrong than for 2, but both have really followed the wrong path, I believe.

Comment: So could you tell me what is the right path here?

Comment: Well, it looks to me like those are PMOS devices. The gates will need to be negative, relative to their source pin. So on first blush, \$V_{DD}\$ needs to be a negative rail so that \$M_2\$ may operate (linear or saturated.) However, the direction of \$I_{in}\$ suggests to me that the gate of \$M_1\$ will be positive, relative to its source, so it is solid OFF and \$V_{out}\$ won't ever budge. But if \$I_{in}\$ is negative, then does this change the meaning of "goes up"?

Comment: Hi, they are nMOS not pMOS here.

Comment: Hmm. I must have a problem seeing the direction of the arrow there or I'm simply confused today. Okay. So they are NMOS.

Comment: That's a really unstable circuit. Assuming Vdd is positive and you have NMOS devices, and Iin is positive, the output is going to be Vdd, until Iin increases into a very tricky area where both M1 and M2 are in a linear region. This won't last long at all (short range of currents), after which the current source will drive point X towards infinity as Vout drives low. It's sudden and crazy-minded. Not really an analyzable schematic. Maybe someone better than me can do it.

Comment: @anhnha The questions are looking more for DC analysis, so the gate capacitance does not enter. My reasoning for 1 would be more like: when Iin goes up, the additional current has to go through M2. Any resistive nature of M2 would cause Vx to rise. As jonk said, the complete circuit is unstable in between, that may be part of the lesson of positive feedback.